# Invalid procedure call or argument in Javascript on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I have a little problem on IE8. Everything works fine on Chrome and FF.

I have a function like this:

```
var Dog = function(){};
```

and I'm able to do this, of course:

```
new Dog();
```

I open a popup window and I try to do this:

```
new window.opener.Dog();
```

and now, only in IE, I get:

```
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

Does anyone knows if it is possible to create an instance of a function defined on the parent window?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `window.opener.Dog` defined? I.e. does `alert(window.opener.Dog)` return something different than `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, it is not undefined. Also, if I open the IE dev panel, and do a console.log(window.opener.Dog), it tells me that Dog is a function, what I expected.

The full problem is: I have a JS object that set some fields in the HTML. I can use this object in the parent window, but if I try to create an instance of it in the popup, i get the error.
Also, if I get an already created instance of the function in the window.opener, I can use it to fill the HTML in the popup.